# How to enable CA_CERTIFICATES on manjaro so that openssl works (xanmod installation error) (solved)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, openssl, manjaro, digital-signature

I'm trying to install the XanMod kernel on a Manjaro machine, but receive errors:

```bsh
$pamac build linux-manjaro-xanmod

  ...
  scripts/sign-file.c:25:10: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
  scripts/extract-cert.c:21:10: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
```

- I have both files on my computer and for some reason the installation doesn't find them. I googled the problem and it seems that it's a problem with `openssl` and `CA_CERTIFICATES`, which have been installed, but I still get the same error after `$sudo update-ca-trust`
- [This](http://github.com/TinkerBoard/debian_kernel/issues/26) claims `CA_CERTIFICATES` should be enabled, but I don't know what more to do with them, as I don't have any certificates to install

Any ideas about what the problem could be?

Solution: The openssl problem is solved by doing

```
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0/pkgconfig
```

prior to running:

```
pamac build linux-manjaro-xanmod
```

The error I got afterwards, namely,

```
 error: Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel
```

is solved by installing `libelf` and `elfutils` which are the equivalents in Manjaro to the 4 mentioned libs. The important part which I forgot was to disable conda, so it was messing the libraries. So I had to do: `conda deactivate` and then to do:

```
pamac build linux-manjaro-xanmod
```

Thanks @JW0914 for the help as his/her comments led me to the solution for the openssl problem.

Comment: Per the link, "_On build root, you must enable `CA_CERTIFICATES` [to] include SSL libraries. ._" e.g. you can't sign or extract certs without the SSL libraries for `openssl`

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe it's obvious, but I don't understand what I need to do. I don't have a certificate to install, just a package to buld. And I don't know how to enable CA_Certificates to include the SSL libraries. Maybe it's something very simple, but I haven't seen it explained so far.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the process of what you're trying to do, but it sounds like `CA_CERTIFICATES` must either be selected within the Kernel's `make menuconfig` or enabled within a makefile in the build root _(e.g. the root directory for your build environment)_

Comment: Probably you're correct, but since I'm using the "pamac" to install it, I have no idea how to reach the makefile. Installing it manually trough  "makepkg -s" 
 gives the same error. There is a config.last file but I don't know what option to add there.

Comment: Have you installed `openssl-utils`/your distro's equivalent, along with the other pre-requisite packages required for compiling/building? Have you checked out [XanMod's Forum](https://forum.xanmod.org/)?

Comment: It seems that for Arch and Manjaro, openssl contains everything. I continued googling and did "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0/pkgconfig" and now I don't get the error, I just get "Failure in prepare()" wihout any meaningful error message. Ah.

Comment: So it gives the following error: 
"error: Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel" even though it has libelf and elfutils installed (which should correspond to the 4 mentioned). It's again related to the openssl, so it seems this is the problem.

Comment: Please add the additional info to your question